# Hooking into 'authenticate' causes login to submit on page load

Tags: php, authentication

I added a filter for the 'autnenticate' hook to apply some additional login verification, but if I change the filter priority to 20, the filter seems to be firing on wp-login page load even if the form is not submitted.

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'custom_login', 20, 3 );
```

Any time, the login page is loaded, this message is always displayed even though nothing is submitted:

```
ERROR: Empty username or password.
```

As this is the first check in the 'custom_login' function:

```
        if($username == '' || $password == '') {
    
            $error = new WP_Error();

            $error->add('empty_username', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Empty username or password.'));
        
            return $error;
    }
```

I am trying to understand why it runs even if the form is not submitted on wp-login page load.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to understand why it runs even if the form is not submitted on wp-login page load.

That's just how it works.

If the current action is `login` which is the *default action*, then [`wp_signon()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/) is always called on page load regardless the login form was submitted or not, and thus your function runs because `wp_signon()` calls [`wp_authenticate()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate/) which fires the [`authenticate` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/authenticate/).

So yes, this is an expected behavior:

> Any time, the login page is loaded, this message is always displayed
> even though nothing is submitted

But it can be prevented.

First, set your callback priority to 20, and secondly, check if the `$user` (the first parameter) is already a `WP_Error` instance and if so, then simply return the instance. E.g.

```php
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'custom_login', 20, 3 ); // set priority to 20 or more
function custom_login( $user, $username, $password ) {
    // The user might already be authenticated, so return the user object.
    if ( $user instanceof WP_User ) {
        return $user;
    }

    // There's already an error authenticating the user, or maybe the user
    // has just landed on the login page, so just return the error object.
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        return $user;
    }

    // ... your validation/code here.

    return $user;
}
```

And I thought it might be worth quoting this from the filter documentation:

> The
> [`wp_authenticate_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_authenticate_user/)
> filter can also be used if you want to perform any additional
> validation after WordPress’s basic validation, but before a user is
> logged in.
>
> The default authenticate filters in /wp-includes/default-filters.php
>
> ```
> add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password',  20, 3 );
> add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_email_password',     20, 3 );
> add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_spam_check',         99    );
> ```

See [`wp_authenticate_username_password()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate_username_password/), [`wp_authenticate_email_password()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate_email_password/) and [`wp_authenticate_spam_check()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate_spam_check/) for details about what the functions do.